# use google to search for real email addresses

Tags: email, search

When a spam email from a company comes in... how can i use google to search for real email adresses at the same domain to get a legitamate unsubscribe or to be an equal nuisance to the company? For example if camelbackford.com sent me unsolicited spam how can i search the internet for real email adresses like "@camelbackford.com"to get me results like sales@camelbackford.com...  When i use google it seems the "@" is not specific enough to only return real possible email adresses at a domain.

Comment: I suspect that google actively prevents searches such as this so as to not provide a method for the aforementioned spammers to get more addresses to spam.

Comment: You don't know who really sent the mail. If it's a legitimate company, they probably didn't send it. Legitimate companies have working unsubscribe links in their mails. If it's a company that actually spams, they're not going to have a real unsubscribe link or contact e-mail for you to find in the first place. Sending mail to them will not annoy them. The only thing answering this question can do is help spammers spam more, and help you annoy companies that never mailed you in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Most real companies have a contact page on their website.